# Filtering nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following `events` array. For every event there is a hash as `{organisation name: [{participant 1}, {participant 2}, {...}]}`

```
"events": [
    {
        "Org A": [
            {
                "event_id": 1,
                "id": 432,
                "name": "John Doe",
                "role": null
            },
            {
                "event_id": 1,
                "id": 312,
                "name": "Jane Mow",
                "role": [
                  "speaker"
                ]
            }
        ],
    }
],
```

I would like to filter this `events` array to only contain participants whose role contains `speaker`. 
Also, when there are no speakers in the participant array, the respective organisation entry needs to be removed from the Hash (object).

To filter the array of objects, I tried using this:

```
_.each(events, function(event){
  _.filter(event, function(p) { 
   _.filter(p, function(d){ 
     return _.some(d.role, function(r){ 
      return r == "speaker"}) 
    }) 
  }) 
})
```

This however doesn't work.

Comment: `d.role` is an array and therefore `r == speaker` will never be true

Comment: your first `_.filter` has no return

Comment: `filter` does return a new array, but you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: _.some checks against each element of an array so why shouldn't d.role be an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var data = {
    "events": [{
        "Org A": [{
            "event_id": 1,
            "id": 432,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "role": null
        }, {
            "event_id": 1,
            "id": 312,
            "name": "Jane Mow",
            "role": [
                "speaker"
            ]
        }],
        
        "Org B": [],
        "Org C": []
    }]
};

var SPEAKER = 'speaker';

var result = _.map(data.events, function (events) {
  return _.chain(events)
    .mapObject(function (value, key) {
      return _.filter(value, function (event) {
        return _.isArray(event.role) && _.indexOf(event.role, SPEAKER) >= 0; 
      });
    })
    .pick(function (value) {
      return value && value.length;
    })
    .value();
})

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```